# log show command output manipulation

Tags: bash, awk, sed, osx, xargs

Following is a command executed on macOS high sierra.

```
**`Command`**

 log show --info --predicate 'process="jamf" and eventMessage contains "Informing the JSS about login for user"' --start 2019-04-25|awk '{printf "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s \n", $1,$2,$4,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18}'|sed '1d'|column -t -s " "|grep -v "Informing  the  JSS  about  login  for  user  root"
```

**`Output:`**

```
 log: warning: ./system_logs.logarchive present but reading from system log store.

2019-04-25  09:49:26.843101+0530  Default  jamf:  [com.jamf.management.binary:all]  Informing  the  JSS  about  login  for  user  swastibhushandeb
2019-04-25  20:14:47.928848+0530  Default  jamf:  [com.jamf.management.binary:all]  Informing  the  JSS  about  login  for  user  swastibhushandeb
```

**`Desired Output:`**

```
2019-04-25  09:49:26.843101+0530  Default  jamf:  [com.jamf.management.binary:all]  Local Login for user  swastibhushandeb 
2019-04-25  20:14:47.928848+0530  Default  jamf:  [com.jamf.management.binary:all]  Local Login for user  swastibhushandeb
```

I understand that the substitution for "`Informing  the  JSS  about  login  for  user  swastibhushandeb`" can be perfromed using `sed 's/Informing  the  JSS  about  login  for  user  swastibhushandeb/Local Login for user  swastibhushandeb/'`

1. But as the username can be different in different scenarios,how can
   the specific field containing the user name from `"Informing  the 
   JSS  about  login  for  user  swastibhushandeb"` be selected and
   substituted?
2. How can column headers be inserted into the output using `awk begin`

Suggestions/sample code to improve the same are welcome .

Comment: We don't know how many columns do you want and the spacing between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your first question is:

```
sed 's/Informing  the  JSS  about  login  for  user/Local Login for user'
```

You suggested right command, but there is no need to replace the `username`, substitute the other words.

For second question, you should provide more details.

Comment: thanks for the input.For the second question,i would like the column headers in red color or underlined.First Column header spanning first column-"Date";Second column header spanning second column-"Time" ;Third Column header spanning third column-"Type";Fourth Column header spanning fourth & fifth column-"bundle";Fifth Column header spanning the last column-"Login Information.". The columns may be equally spaced and that which could be preferable for users easy viewing.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly pipeline output which you got to below command

i removed the warning line log: warning: and added the header which you have mentioned Everything done by awk  with correct space formatting

command

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "Date Time Type bundle Logininformation"}NR >1{gsub("Informing\t  the  JSS  about","Local",$0);print $0}' k.txt|sed '/^$/d'| awk '{printf "%30s%30s%30s%30s%30s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5}'| awk '$0 !~/^$/{print $0}'
```

output

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "Date Time Type bundle Logininformation"}NR >1{gsub("Informing\t  the  JSS  about","Local",$0);print $0}' k.txt|sed '/^$/d'| awk '{printf "%30s%30s%30s%30s%30s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5}'| awk '$0 !~/^$/{print $0}'
                          Date                          Time                          Type                        bundle              Logininformation
                    2019-04-25          09:49:26.843101+0530                       Default                         jamf:[com.jamf.management.binary:all]
                    2019-04-25          20:14:47.928848+0530                       Default                         jamf:[com.jamf.management.binary:all]
```